# Solr POST Request returns 400. Java. When size of request is too large

Tags: java, solr, jetty

I'm sending a query to solr using POST request.  Everything works well. There is a scenario when I've to send some string in the filter query like:

```
fq=id:("id1""id2""id3")
```

When the length of the filter query is above a certain threshold, I keep getting Err 400: Bad Request.

This error is coming form the underlying Jetty server above the solr that I'm using.

What is the workaround for this? Should I be increasing the size of the post request body in Jetty?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the logs? I tried it and got this in logs `org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser; URI is too large >8192`    `org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser; badMessage: 414 for HttpChannelOverHttp@6475fcbf{r=0,c=false,a=IDLE,uri=-}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increase the below value and try...

```
<maxBooleanClauses>1024</maxBooleanClauses>
```

This sets the maximum number of clauses allowed in a boolean query. This can affect range or prefix queries that expand to a query with a large number of boolean terms. If this limit is exceeded, an exception is thrown.

for more info check

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Query+Settings+in+SolrConfig